# Find Maximum sum in a path in a 2D matrix with positive integers

Tags: optimization, matrix, path, sum, max

I would like to know where I can read about algorithms for solving this problem efficiently:

- Four directions allowed: up, down, left, right
- Cells containing zero can't be visited.
- Visiting the same cell twice is illegal.
- Moves wraps around the edges:
- (first row is connected with last row)
- (first col is connected with last col)

Example, 5x5 and 5 steps:

```
  9  1  3  1  9
  6  3  2  4  1
  0  7  *  7  7
  5  4  9  4  9
  7  9  1  5  5
```

Starting point: *

Solution: down,left,down,left,down. That is 9 + 4 + 9 + 7 + 9 = 38

```
 [9] 1  3  1  9
  6  3  2  4  1
  0  7  *  7  7
  5 [4][9] 4  9
 [7][9] 1  5  5
```

This problem is probably **not** related to:

- Finding the maximum sub matrix
- Dynamic programming

Comment: To clarify, the path length 'k' is an input parameter?

Comment: Yes, the path length is an input parameter. The sum and path are output parameters.

Comment: Is there a relation between matrix size n and path length k? I think the problem becomes very different for cases where k < n than for k > n.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet, but I feel like the problem could be transformed into a graph problem (vertex = non-0 matrix elements, edge = any U/D/L/R non-0 pair) and handled with Branch and Bound with bounds similar to that of the Knapsack problem. Start with 2-paths and expand them in order of current value or potential.

Comment: k + z must be less than n*n, z being number of zeros.

Comment: How many vertices and edges will the sample matrix transform to?

Comment: The vertex set size will be n-z (every non-zero matrix element is a vertex), the edge set will be 2*(n-z). This is a very sparse graph, making many graph-search algorithms efficient.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the sizes.

Comment: I'm still not sure about how to solve the problem. I'm used to shortest path problems, but this is different. In SP a reached node is reached forever. In this problem nodes may come and go. I have a recursive solution, but it takes one minute for k=20 in a 5x5 torus. My goal is a sub second solution.

Comment: I think your problem can be solved in O(2^(k-1)) at best in the general case (with given starting point). Depending on the nature of the data it may be possible to prune further. Is there a known, fixed range of values your elements can take, eg. [0, 9] as in your example? One minute for k=20 in 5x5 seems long; I'll see if I can do better.

Comment: Just realized a mistake in my reasoning. It's going to be roughly O(4 * 3 ^ (k-1)), but for values of K near n² it's going to do better than the theoretical bound.

Comment: Yes, the range is [0,9]. Your complexity analysis seems correct to. There is a cut possibility too. Having reached a so far best sum, it is possible to avoid branches in the tree that can't produce a higher sum. Especially if higher values are investigated before neighbours with lower values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified in comments that you wanted a sub-second way of finding the best value 20-step path out of a 5x5 matrix. I've implemented a basic recursive search tree that does this. Ultimately, the difficulty of this is still O(3^k), but highly saturated cases like yours (21 out of 24 allowed nodes visited) will solve much faster because the problem simplifies to "skip the n*n-z-k-1 lowest value cells" (in this case, n=5, z=1 and k+1 = 21; the winning path skips three 1's).

The problem instance in your question solves in 0.231seconds on a 3 year old i5 laptop and about half a second on ideone.com. I've provided code here http://ideone.com/5kOyxq (note that '`up`' and '`down`' are reversed because of the way I input the data).

For less saturated problems you may need to add a Bound/Cut method. You can generate a Bound as follows:

First, run over the NxN matrix and collect the K highest value elements (can be done in N² log K) and sort them by max-first. Then, cumulatively calculate the value UB[t] = SUM[i::0->t] SortedElements[i]. So, any t-length path has a UB of UB[t] (max t elements).

At step T, the current Branch's UB is UB[t]. If ValueSoFar[T] + UB[K-T] <= BestPathValue, you can stop that branch.

There may be better ways, but this should be sufficient for reasonably sized matrices and path lengths.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I got much more than I expected! We are using the same algorithm, although different languages. http://ideone.com/UOAMZO

Comment: Ah, too bad I couldn't provide you with new insights. Is switching to a faster language an option, or do you need extra performance?

Comment: I will probably rewrite the optimizer in C and call it from Ruby. Another possibility is to stop searching after, say, one second, and use what is found, even though this is not the best solution.

Comment: Can I ask what the application is?

Answer (score 0):

Game or puzzle. Given a matrix, number of steps and a sum, find the path.
Would be nice if there is a real world application for this, but i haven't found it. 
Games tend to "burn in" knowledge in young brains, so why not burn in something useful, like addition?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
#define R 3
#define C 3

int MAX(int x, int y, int z);

int Max_Cost(int cost[R][C], int m, int n)
{
   if (n < 0 || m < 0)
      return INT_MIN;

   else if (m == 0 && n == 0)
      return cost[m][n];

   else
      return cost[m][n] + MIN( Max_Cost(cost, m-1, n-1),
                               Max_Cost(cost, m-1, n), 
                               Max_Cost(cost, m, n-1)
                             );
}

int MAX(int x, int y, int z)
{
  return max(max(x, y), z);
}

int main()
{
  int cost[R][C] = { {3, 2, 5},
                     {5, 8, 2},
                     {9, 7, 1}
                   };
  cout<<Max_Cost(cost, 2, 1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some more information to your answer.

Comment: The code does not seem to visit the square 2,2. Also no wrapping. Not forking out in four direction. I have not run it though.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.